# Relación a una clave foránea de la misma tabla MySql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Necesito registrar en una bd 2 tipos de personas: **Deportistas** y los **acudientes** de los deportistas.

Los campos de ambos son técnicamente los mismos (nombre, apellido, tel..), salvo  los **acudientes** que se requiere un campo adicional (id_factura), y los **deportistas** que requieren un campo adicional (id_acudiente)

En un principio, pensé crear una tabla para ambos llamada: **usuarios**, e incluir los campos de ambos, algo como:

```
 ---------------------------
|         usuarios         |
 ---------------------------
| id             | int(11) |
| nombre         | varchar |
| apellido       | varchar |
| telefono       | varchar |
| rol            | int(11) |
| id_factura     | int(11) |
----------------------------
```

pero entré en duda por el campo de **id_acudiente**, ya que en los registros de las personas con rol **deportista** tienen su respectivo acudiente de la misma tabla sólo que con rol **acudiente**

Entonces pensé hacerlo así:

```
 ---------------------------
|         usuarios         |
 ---------------------------
| id             | int(11) |
| nombre         | varchar |
| apellido       | varchar |
| telefono       | varchar |
| rol            | int(11) |
| id_factura     | int(11) |
| id_acudiente   | int(11) |
----------------------------
```

Permitiendo el campo **id_acudiente** ser nulo, en caso de que el registro sea el de un acudiente.

La pregunta es, ¿está bien hecho de ésta manera? ¿o es mejor tener las tablas por separadas (una para deportistas y otra para acudiente)?

Comment: El planteo que haces es correcto. Es totalmente válido tener una foreign key en un tabla a si misma. Id_factura tiene que admitir nulos obviamente y el modelo es correcto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te propongo hacer uso de los conceptos de especialización y generalización creando una tabla común para todos los usuarios independientemente de su rol (generalización), y crear tablas de especialización para cada uno de ellos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aporto el dataset para que puedas probarlo:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  id_usuario int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(15),
  apellido varchar(15),
  telefono varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE facturas(
  id_factura int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  );
CREATE TABLE deportistas(
  id_usuario int,
  id_acudiente int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(id_usuario),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_acudiente) REFERENCES usuarios(id_usuario)
  );
CREATE TABLE acudientes(
  id_usuario int,
  id_factura int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(id_usuario),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_factura) REFERENCES facturas(id_factura)
  );
```

La ventaja de este diseño frente a tu propuesta es que te ahorras el campo `rol` y que no desperdicirás espacio con campos que sabes que se van a quedar vacíos.

En cambio, a tu diseño le veo una ventaja operativa: que tendrás más controlados a los usuarios por el hecho de definir su rol al crearlos. De esta forma, si un usuario tiene rol de deportista y tiene el `id_acudiente` a `NULL`, podrás detectar inconsistencias.

Lo que no te recomiendo en ningún caso es crear dos tablas separadas de usuarios con campos en común. En el caso de que un acudiente fuera también deportista, tendrías datos duplicados.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias David por tu respuesta. 
Una pequeña duda más, en caso de que necesite otro campo en cualquiera de las dos tablas (que no sea foráneo), lo agrego a la tabla de **usuarios**, o lo agrego directamente a la tabla en el que lo necesito?

Comment: Me alegra que os haya gustado :). Si es común a todos los usuarios, como el email, pues directamente en `usuarios`. Si es específico de un tipo de usuario, mejor en su tabla. Se trata de evitar la redundancia de datos en todo lo posible. Si te gusta este tema, puedes buscar más información sobre modelado de datos (modelos ER y relacional), así como normalización. Parece muy teórico, pero las aplicaciones prácticas lo compensan... Estoy a tu disposición para profundizar en ello

Comment: @DavidJP, mil gracias de nuevo por tu colaboración y ayuda, ahora mismo me acabo de topar con una dudita ya que ando haciendo de nuevo la bd pero en mySQL, y es en el momento de registrar un deportista o acudiente, el registro se haría a las dos tablas al mismo tiempo? (usuario y la otra entidad)

Comment: Por ejemplo, necesito registrar un nuevo deportista, entonces el formulario la mitad de los campos se registrarían en mi tabla **Usuarios**, y la otra mitad en la tabla **Deportistas**?, o se hace de otra manera el registro?

Comment: Sí, tal como comentas: los campos comunes a todos los usuarios estarán en la tabla `usuarios` y los específicos de deportistas en `deportistas`. Recuerda que, en `deportistas` tienes un `id_usuario` que indica con quién está vinculado

Comment: Hola @DavidJP, mil gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda.
David, me puedes ayudar con ésta por favor?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/323973/109858

Comment: Acabo de verla y ya te la han respondido, no he llegado a tiempo :)