# Consulta a dos tablas en SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mvc, poo

Estoy haciendo un **Login** en PHP (MVC) con acceso a sólo dos tipos de perfiles: las personas de la tabla **administradores** y las personas de la tabla **entrenadoras**. 
En un principio, pensé en hacer una sóla consulta a ambas tablas para buscar coincidencias con las credenciales del usuario que se estuviera logueando, pero ¿cómo sé de qué tabla viene dicho usuario desde una sóla consulta?, quizá si agregando un campo más que diga **rol** a la consulta, lo pueda identificar más fácil; ¿pero cómo se puede hacer?

Éstas son mis tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y éste es un fragmento del código donde hago la consulta:

**Controlador:**

```
static public function ctrIngresoUsuario(){

   if(isset($_POST["Usuario"])){

      $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios(//Aquí mando las credenciales);

      if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["Usuario"] && $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["password"]){    

      //Y aquí es donde necesito validar qué tipo de usuario viene (administrador o entrenadora) para darle sus respectivos permisos
      $_SESSION["rol"] = $respuesta["rol"]; //<- Aquí iría el rol que viene en la consulta

   }

}
```

**Y en el modelo `ModeloUsuarios`:**

```
static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios(//Recibo las credenciales para buscarlo){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("La consulta a las dos tablas");

    $stmt -> bindParam(//Enlazo parámetros);

    $stmt -> execute();

    return $stmt -> fetch();

}
```

En pocas palabras, necesito darle acceso al sistema a cualquiera que esté registrado en las tablas **entrenadoras** o **administradores**

Comment: El problema que yo veo aquí es el siguiente. Deberías tener todo en la misma tabla, usuarios. Y tener un campo (por ejemplo del tipo Enum) que te permite indicar si ese usuario es Entrenador o Administrador. Lo que quieres hacer, se puede hacer. Pero no es para nada eficiente.

Comment: Hola @candelo Creo que puedes mejorar la lógica del modelo de datos así: una sola tabla para usuarios, una tabla de grupos de usuarios, y una tabla de relación entre usuarios y grupos de usuarios, de modo que un usuario puede pertenecer a varios grupos y se hace fácil el manejo de privilegios y perfiles. La idea no es mía así lo hace [Drupal] que es posiblemente uno de los mejores CMS orientados a la web.

Comment: Observa que en tu diseño parece haber el supuesto de que una Entrenadora no pueda ser jugadora y eso tendría sentido en un colegio o en una institución con sólo un equipo. Te pongo un ejemplo con los dos roles: La liga de Ajedrez de Bogotá, algunos de sus mejores jugadores son también entrenadores de las selecciones de varias de sus divisiones.

Comment: Gracias @quevedo por tus aportes.
El sistema va dirigido a un club de natación, por lo que, tanto las entrenadoras como el resto de usuarios, tienen más campos diferentes (nómima, etc..), por lo que dudo mucho la distribución con la tabla **grupos de usuarios** como me comentaste.

Comment: Por otro lado, las entrenadoras no creo (o no lo sé la verdad) que puedan llegar a ser jugadoras también.., de hecho, gracias por comentarmelo, lo preguntaré.

Comment: Una observación @candelo Es cierto que los usuarios pueden tener diferencias en los campos (cantidad y naturaleza) que se usan para recoger su info. Pero, la información minima necesaria para definir un usuario es la misma para todos. Eso determina la tabla de usuarios. La información diferencial, da lugar a tablas vinculadas de propósito específico. Puedes usar un diseño de clases para ello. Una clase básica "usuario" que es extendida por otras que reflejan las necesidades...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacer un inner join de las tres tablas y luego verificar si el campo id administrador es vacío podrías determinar el rol.

```
SELECT u.*, 
   case when a.id_usuario <> null 
        then 'administrador' 
        else 'entrenador' 
        end as 'rol',
   case when a.password <> null 
        then a.password
        else e.password
        end as 'password'
    from usuarios as u
    inner join administradores as a
      on u.id = a.id_usuario
    inner join entrenadoras as e
      on u.id = e.id_usuario
```

Pero te sugiero que reveas la estructura de tus tablas para ver si esto tiene sentido.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias maestro!
La estructura de las tablas es en base a éste paradigma: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/319292/109858

Comment: Hice unas pequeñas modificaciones a la consulta que me diste, para que me retornara los datos de la tabla según el usuario que consultara, y me funcionó de ésta manera: `SELECT us.*, CASE WHEN ad.id_usuario = us.id THEN (SELECT password FROM administradores) ELSE (SELECT password FROM entrenadoras) END AS 'rol' FROM usuarios us LEFT JOIN administradores ad ON us.id = ad.id_usuario LEFT JOIN entrenadoras en ON us.id = en.id_usuario WHERE us.id = '1036442198'`
(Claro, porque también necesitaba comparar el password)

Comment: Pero ahora que ya tengo el password del usuario que intenta loguearse para validarlo, no sé ya de qué manera obtengo el rol :/

Comment: Pensé en hacerlo así: `SELECT us.*, CASE WHEN ad.id_usuario = us.id THEN (SELECT password FROM administradores) ELSE (SELECT password FROM entrenadoras) END AS 'password', CASE WHEN ad.id_usuario = us.id THEN 'administradora' ELSE 'entrenadora' END AS 'rol' FROM usuarios us LEFT JOIN administradores ad ON us.id = ad.id_usuario LEFT JOIN entrenadoras en ON us.id = en.id_usuario WHERE us.id = '1036442198'`

Pero creo que es bastante redundante y largo...

Comment: Fijate la query, ahi te agregué el campo password para que puedas obtenerlo junto con el rol. Decime si te sirvió y no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta si te sirvió :). Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero me faltó poner la condición de que en caso que sea **administradora**, también me traiga el perfil que está en la tabla de **administradores**, el mismo que aparece en la imagen... ¿es igual que las consultas anteriores, pero con una condición de más?

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo que crees mejor una tabla tipo rol osea en la tabla puedes crear un rol de administrador y un rol de entrenador por decir
id rol
1  Administrador
2  Entrenador

con esto solo debes hacer una relación en esta tabla y la tabla de usuarios y así dependiendo el id sabes quien es administrador y quien es entrenador, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Con esta consulta obtienes usuarios que son administradores o entrenadoras. En caso positivo, devuelve registro, en caso negativo no devuelve ninguna fila.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM usuarios
left join entrenadoras b on a.id = b.id_usuario
left join andministradores c on a.id = c.id_usuario
where b.id_usuario is not null and c.id_usuario is not null
and a.ID = loquesea
```

Answer (score 1):

No te compliques la vida , las tablas que tienes como entrenadores y administrador conviértela en un tabla de roles, así al momento de realizar el login desde ahí determinas que rol tiene y en base a esto que privilegios de acceso.

En mi caso y por necesidades del actual sistema los roles los asigne de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así controlo el nivel de acceso, que puede o no ver, utilizar o modificar cada usuario en base a su nivel de acceso, incluso hasta mostrar el nombre de su rol en una ficha de usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno yo lo veo de dos modos. 
primero que nada ambas tablas tienen que tener un identificador que les diferencie entres el tipo de usuario, si Paty es Entrenadora tenga el rol entrenador (1), y si Juan es Administrador tenga ese rol de administrador (2). si al checar en la aplicación algo a lo que tenga que tener acceso  le pones un

```
if (Roll = 1) { "boton" }
```

Así podrás jugar mas con permisos mas complejos a futuro (siempre y cuando conecten a la misma herramienta)

yo propondría columnas con permisos roles idioma y cosas asi adicional en una tabla aparte o en cada usuario, así podras traer con tu sección estos valores (después de asociar que sean correctas las credenciales claro)

```
if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["Usuario"] && $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["password"]){    


        if(is_array($respuesta) && !empty($respuesta)) {
            $validuser = $row['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['valid'] = $validuser;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $row['nombre'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        }
```

la otra opción es que tengas una tabla independiente a la cual tengan relación los usuarios 
Si paty tiene en su campo rol 2 y checamos que tiene la tabla roles en el id = 1 , nos podrá decir que tiene idioma 1 (ingles), edicion 1 (si puede editar), borrar NULL (no puede borra )
algo como permisos fijos según tipo de rol en cada consulta